# Change Local path, team explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Does any one know how to change the local path of the downloaded project in team explorer 2008. I downloaded a project to a wrong directory, now i deleted it and did get latest but i get a message 
"All files are up to date"

Thanks
-Mithil

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the source-control explorer click in the "workspaces..." option in the "Workspace:" Dropdown.
And then edit your workspace or set a new one.

When you recive the message that you mention, you can Get a specific->latest version 
with all the checkboxes checked.

Comment: It seems to re-map to the new folder OK and clear up what it can from the previous one, but (for me at least) it left behind the Bin and Obj folders with some large files there. So if you're trying to clear space from one drive to another (or move away from using a roaming profile folder to speed up logging in/out of Windows) be aware that you may need to do a little manual clearing up after the move.